# Haxe macros, calling static method from generated var setter

Tags: macros, haxe

I'm adding getter and setters to a variable using haxe macros, now I'm stuck trying to call a static function from within the newly generated setter:

```js
public static function build():Array<Field> {
//.........
// create setter
var setterBody = macro {
    $variableRef = v;
    // mypackage.MyClass.myFunc(this) <-------- DOES NOT WORK!!
    return $variableRef;
};
newFields.push({
    pos: Context.currentPos(),
    name: "set_" + field.name,
    meta: [],
    kind: FieldType.FFun({
            ret: readType,
            params: [],
            expr: setterBody,
            args: [{
                value: null,
                type: readType,
                opt: false,
                name: "v"
            }]
        }),
    doc: "",
    access: []
});
```

In the code above I can't find a way to call `MyClass.myFun(this)`, I don't know how to generate that code for the setter, `this` refers to the instance of the object where the setter is called.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a more complete example it's hard to know what went wrong.  What I can do is show you code that works:

**TiagoLrMacroTest.hx**:

```
@:build( TiagoLrMacro.build() )
class TiagoLrMacroTest {
    public static function main() {
        var test = new TiagoLrMacroTest();
        test.name = "hello";
    }

    function new() {}

    public var name(default,set):String;
}

class MyStaticClass {
        public static function staticMethod( a:TiagoLrMacroTest ) {
        trace( a.name );
    }
}
```

**TiagoLrMacro.hx**

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Context;

class TiagoLrMacro {
    public static function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var setterBody = macro {
            name = v;
            TiagoLrMacroTest.MyStaticClass.staticMethod( this );
            return name;
        };
        fields.push({
            pos: Context.currentPos(),
            name: "set_name",
            meta: [],
            kind: FieldType.FFun({
                ret: macro :String,
                params: [],
                expr: setterBody,
                args: [{
                    value: null,
                    type: macro :String,
                    opt: false,
                    name: "v"
                }]
            }),
            doc: "",
            access: []
        });
        return fields;
    }
}
```

**Result** (Haxe 3.1.3):

```
TiagoLrMacroTest.hx:15: hello
```

The one common gotcha I run into with calling static methods in macros is that imports are not respected, so you have to use full type paths like `mypackage.MyClass.myFunc(this)`, but you are already doing this, so the error must be somewhere else in your code.  Happy macro-ing :)

Comment: It worked, funny i still can't figure what i was doing wrong, makes no sense, the important thing is that it works, thanks.

Comment: Always frustrating!  Hope you can narrow it down and either figure it out or get a reproducible sample so we can help :)